# Spring project how to set realtive and absolute path to get a properties file?

Tags: java, spring

I got a source code from my team, and this is a spring framework project. but little different from before.

Okay I got a problem with get properties file from java code. this is my simple structure project :

```
root
 |- src
    |- log4j.properties
    |- persistent.properties
    |- id.com.my.api.elastic.utils
       |- StaticVariable.java
```

I need to load 2 properties file to `StaticVariable.java` properly

this is my code for now :

```
public static final String PROPERTIES_PATH = "/src/persistent.properties";
public static final String LOG4J_PATH = "/src/log4j.properties";
```

but when I run on tomcat server still not found this file, so I changed :

```
public static final String PROPERTIES_PATH = "..\\persistent.properties";
public static final String LOG4J_PATH = "..\\log4j.properties";
```

Also not found, how to solve this?

this is how the previous programmer use the code :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "id.com.my.api.elastic")
@PropertySource("file:" + StaticVariable.PROPERTIES_PATH)
public class SpringJDBCConfiguration {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static final String PROPERTIES_PATH = "/persistent.properties";
public static final String LOG4J_PATH = "/log4j.properties";
```

those paths wil work with `Class#getResource` and `Class#getResourceAsStream`

As for your update:

You are requesting source to be a file - this wont work after packaging application - probably will work only in IDE. Insted of

```
@PropertySource("file:" + StaticVariable.PROPERTIES_PATH)
```

it should be

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/persistent.properties")
```

and

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/log4j.properties")
```

Read more here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

Comment: Oh my god, you really an angel for me today, thanks dude

Comment: @yozawiratama consider accepting the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: yes dude, still waiting to accept the answer, cant accept after 5 minutes, thanks